# Browser does not replace special characters

Tags: html

When inserted into the "title" text with character codes - they are not replaced.
Example:
**Original text:** 0001_SomeText_Test
**After replacing underscores**

```
0001&#95;SomeText&#95;Test
```

[Displays the DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjECU.png)

Can you please tell how to fix a text display?

Comment: Place `<meta charset='utf-8'>` in the `<head>`

Comment: Thank you, said in another answer

Comment: Is this still a problem? Can you point to a website where this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting <meta charset='utf-8'> in the <head> tag of your page

Comment: Thanks, the page already contains the correct encoding: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">. File with layout encoded utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding your code with notepad++ :
enconding > UTF-8 
Save and upload

Or try to change the encoding of your web browser, for chrome :
Parameter > Language and input parameter